# Combine two tables using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables

```
Id   name
---------------
1   camera
2   computer
3   tv

ColorId color
----------------
1       black
2       orange  
3       blue
```

And I need to combine both on the following way in SQL Server:

```
Id  name        colorId color
--------------------------------
1   camera      1       black
1   camera      2       orange
1   camera      3       blue
2   computer    1       black
2   computer    2       orange
2   computer    3       blue
3   tv          1       black
3   tv          2       orange
3   tv          3       blue
```

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: You need to read about the various types of joins as this is the basis of pulling data from more than 1 table. https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **cross join** between tables, it will returns all posible combinations between tables you use

```
select *
from table_1 cross join table_2
```